# Where are my AWS Libs which I imported with nuget

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core

I have a small project taking advantage of the AWS SDK. The SDK is imported with nuget and tells me everything is fine. It compiles but as soon as I want to debug it the necessary aws libs can't be found. I certainly can put them into the folders manually but I assume this is not the correct way using nuget packages.
It is a dotnet core application. I had a dotnet framework application before and as I remember correctly there was not such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to build it in release mode or publish it, the required dll files will automatically be copied. As far as the debugging is concerned, try adding the dll files in Global Assembly Cache;

navigate to the directory with gacutil.exe file and run this command:

**gacutil.exe /i "path to assembly.dll"**